# Translating a system of polynomials into a system of partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

The book Solving Systems of Polynomial Equations by Bernd Sturmfels claims that you can translate a system of polynomials into a system of partial differential equations. The example given is the equation:

$\sum ci_{1}i_{2}...i_{n}x_{1}^{il}x_{2}^{i2}...x_{n}^{in}$=0

can be translated to

$\sum ci_{1}i_{2}...i_{n} \frac{\partial^{i_{1} + i_{2} + ... + i_{n}}f}{\partial_{x1}^{i_{l}}\partial_{x2}^{i_{2}}...\partial_{xn}^{i_{n}}}$ =0

for an unknown function
$f = f(x_1, . . . , x_n)$.

My question is where does this translation come from?

Comment: Also, $f$ has gotten sucked into the exponent on the $\partial$.

Comment: Isn't that what Sturmfels is trying to explain in the rest of the chapter? (For example in Section 10.1, ”Why Differential Equations?”)

Comment: He shows why the PDE formulation is better, but not where the translation from polynomial system to PDE system comes from, which is what I don't know.

Comment: Not really sure what it is you’re looking for here. If the polynomial is $P(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, then the associated differential equation is clearly $P(\partial/\partial x_1,\dots,\partial/\partial x_n)f=0$. The solutions are intimately connected to the roots of $P$, as I’m sure the text goes on to explain.